# How to jump back to beginning of an if statement if user inputs wrong answer

Tags: java, if-statement, input

Here is the code:

```
if (g1 == 6) {
   System.out.println("Correct! Proceed to the next challenge");
} 
else {  
   System.out.println("That is incorrect, please try again");
}
```

How do I allow them to try again if, for example they input "4" for their guess?
Basically, how do I go back to the beginning of the `if` statement?

Answer (score 4):

```
String g1 = "";
try {
    InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
    do {
      g1 = in.readLine();
      if (g1 == 6) {
        System.out.println("Correct! Proceed to the next challenge");
      } else {
        System.out.println("That is incorrect, please try again");
      }
    } while(g1 != 6);
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error! Exception: "+e); 
}
```

Comment: I did that and ran it. I typed in 8 and instead of trying again it kept spamming "That is incorrect, please try again" over and over until I stopped it.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  All you have to do is put the statement where you read the user's input inside the loop before your if/else validations.

If you find this helpful please vote up and mark the answer as correct.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

This is what `while` loops are designed for.

In learning to program focus on thinking about the `sequence` of instructions through `if` and `while` constructs.  If you get a suggestion that gives you some details, read it.  Understand it.

Think about what it's doing, what you want it to do - and how you might bridge that gap.

If you're asking why something is "spamming", your thoughts should turn toward what else needs to be going on *inside* the loop that's causing the spam.